# Calculating $\int_0^{\pi/4} \frac{\cot (x)}{\cot ^2(x)+\sqrt{\cot (x)}} \, dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

This is not really one of that kind of integrals that *Mathematica* cannot handle with, but given
the case of a contest, how would we like to handle with it? I would like so much to know your 
ideas  about tackling such integrals. Can we make things here really simple? *Solutions are optional*.

Calculate

$$\int_0^{\pi/4} \frac{\cot (x)}{\cot ^2(x)+\sqrt{\cot (x)}} \, dx$$

*Supplementary question:* calculate

$$\int_0^{\pi/4} \frac{x \cot (x)}{\cot ^2(x)+\sqrt{\cot (x)}} \, dx.$$

Comment: Do you know the closed form of the second integral? my mathematica isn't able to do it...

Comment: @tired I'm working on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just let
$$
u=\cot x.
$$
You will get the integral
$$
\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{u}{u^2+\sqrt{u}}\frac{1}{1+u^2}\,du,
$$
which I'm sure you can handle with your skills (just let $s=\sqrt{u}$ and you have a rational function).

Comment: You're so great at integration (+1). I felt we could use some clever double integrals and finish all very fast, but ...

Comment: I'm nothing compared to some gurus on this site. I hope one of them will calculate the integral with the additional $x$. I'm not able, so far.

Comment: I think you're greater than almost all I know (well, just the opinion of a self-educated).

Comment: That second integral you may try this property $f(x)=f(a-x)$ when integrating from $0$ to $a$ since there is an $x$ in the denom.

Comment: @imranfat If you think of the usual trick integrating $x f(\sin x)$, I don't think it work here. At least I'm not able to find the wanted symmetry, since $\cot(\pi/4-x)=(\cot x+1)/(\cot x-1)$.

Comment: @mickep It was just a thing that came in my mind. Wolfram couldn't find an anti derivative and that $x$ made me thing that perhaps.....So since this is a supplementary question, is there then supposed to be a way?

Comment: I have no clue if there is a nice and simple answer. Maybe @Chris'ssistheartist has an ace up his/her sleeve?